# VS2008: Add custom build rule to a Property Sheet (vsprops)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, custom-build-step, vsprops

I'm using the CUDA .rules file which comes with the CUDA SDK for custom build steps in my project.
To save on property duplication I'd like to define the properties of the CUDA rule in a .vsprops file. For some reason, the CUDA rule branch of the properties tree does not show under any of my property sheets, only under the main configurations sheets.
I tried editing the .vsprops with a text edition and add the  section by hand but there is no change it still does't show when in visual studio.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nancy answered the question here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vcgeneral/thread/1971a75e-a551-4319-b014-1977c797b1c0)

> "As far as I know, there is not
>    element in XML schema for
>   property sheets, for details, please
>   see:
>
> XML Schema Definition for Property
>   Sheets
>
> So I don't think you can add custom
>   build rule to a Property Sheet. For
>   your reference, in VS 2010, Custom
>   build rule changes, in VS 2008 custom
>   build rule is defined by a .rules
>   file, Conversion will convert these
>   .rules files into three separate
>   files: .targets, .xml and .props, See
>   Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project Upgrade
>   Guide for more information."

Hope it helps others : )

Comment: Nice auto collect of a juicy bounty.  Posting the response that Nancy posted to shoosh's own question (shoosh appears to be Shy Shalom on MSDN).

Comment: Hmm...good response.  At first i thought it was kind of cheesy but that info is useful to the community in general even if the OP already has the answer. +1